# rlwrap mac os x install error

Tags: macos, command-line, sqlplus, rlwrap

I am trying to install RLWrap into my mac os x (Snow Leopard), I have XCode and am able to run the `./configure` command sucessfuly, however when I try the `make` command I get the following error:

> make  all-recursive Making all in doc make[2]: Nothing to be done for
>   `all'. Making all in src gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..
>   -DDATADIR=\"/usr/local/share\"  -g -O2 -MT main.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/main.Tpo -c -o main.o main.c main.c: In function
>   ‘read_options_and_command_name’: main.c:775: error:
>   ‘rl_basic_quote_characters’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>   main.c:775: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
>   main.c:775: error: for each function it appears in.) make[2]: ***
>   [main.o] Error 1 make[1]:**  [all-recursive] Error 1 make: ** [all]
>   Error 2

Anyone have any ideas of the cause of this?

Comment: The code looks broken.  Where is it from?

Comment: It's literally just the RLWrap installer, several guides online state that once the ./configure is complete (It is) run 'make' and 'make install', this is what happens after running the first make.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though there's a bogus libreadline on OS X:

```
oldhost:rlwrap-0.37 boxcat$ ls -l /usr/lib/libreadline.dylib 
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  15 16 Mar 14:25 /usr/lib/libreadline.dylib -> libedit.3.dylib
oldhost:rlwrap-0.37 boxcat$
```

I think you'll need a genuine libreadline (i.e. the GNU version) installed first.